# What's the difference between running "rspec spec" and "rspec spec/controllers"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having a very interesting problem. When I run my specs with `rspec spec/controllers`, they all pass. When I run them with `rspec spec`, they fail.

Here's how they're failing:

```
✗ rspec spec 
F...........

Failures:

  1) PeopleBridge::OAuthController GET login redirects
     Failure/Error: cookies.clear
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `stringify_keys' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/people_bridge/o_auth_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.04187 seconds
12 examples, 1 failure
```

I have a strong suspicion that the particular error I'm getting is not the important part. I've spent quite a while going down that rabbit hole already. My curiosity now is **what's the difference between running `rspec spec/controllers` and `rspec/spec`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `rspec spec` all of your tests are running, not only controller tests. I could imagine that there is a unexpected correlation between the controller and another test that only is being run when you run the whole test suite. Probably something is initialized or not cleaned up correctly.

Try to specify varying combinations of tests to find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Turns out I was monkey patching `Hash#with_indifferent_access` in a different test and that's what was causing the problem.

Comment: Ack! monkey patching in a test. Are really testing your application if you need to alter activesupport within your unit tests to get them to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is specified after `rspec` is just the file or the directory of files that rspec is going to run.

Your error may appear due to something that is done previous to the failing test execution, something that is done outside the spec/controllers directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```
bundle exec rake spec
```

Comment: That just outputs nothing at all.